# Google Protocol Buffer error: "Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while serializing protocol buffer"

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am using the following code

```
int lenSend = odl->ByteSize();
char* buf = (char *)malloc(lenSend);
odl->SerializeToArray(buf, lenSend);
```

I get this error and I can't understand why I get it (yes I get it three times):

> libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format.cc:1059] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while serializing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes' type for raw bytes.
>   libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format.cc:1059] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while serializing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes' type for raw bytes.
>   libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format.cc:1059] Encountered string containing invalid UTF-8 data while serializing protocol buffer. Strings must contain only UTF-8; use the 'bytes' type for raw bytes.

Thanks.

Comment: I should note that the data gets to the other side (using GPB for payload over a socket) and it looks fine, but the other side complains with the same message on de-serialization. Can I just suppress this message?

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to make a simple api call with a json url param. Any clue how to make the server side not treat it as a GRPC call?

Answer (score 13):

You can get rid of the warning by following the advice in the message!

You must have a field or fields in the definition of `odl` (in your .proto file) which are defined as `string` but into which you are putting non-UTF-8 characters.  [The docs state that you shouldn't do this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar).  If you change these to `bytes`, the warnings should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

In golang, you can use strings.ToValidUTF8 to avoid temporary

Answer (score 0):

string  A string must always contain UTF-8 encoded or 7-bit ASCII text. string  String  str/unicode[4]

bytes   May contain any arbitrary sequence of bytes.    string  ByteString  str

somtimes you should user bytes instead of string!

Answer (score 0):

Use byte[] to replace string, which encoding is not UTF-8 or ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Convert []byte for translate

Example:

```
message Data {
    Object obj = 1;
}
```

If `<grpc: failed to unmarshal the received message string field contains invalid UTF-8>`:

```
# marshal object
message Data {
    bytes encodeObject = 1;
}
# unmarshal object
```