# ParDo did not have a ParDoPayload

Tags: go, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've written a Beam pipeline in Go that runs successfully on my local machine, but when I add `--runner=dataflow` to run it on Google Cloud Dataflow I get a vague error when it's setting up that a ParDo is missing a ParDoPayload.  The stacktrace is entirely Java, so I'm not sure how to translate this back into my Go code to figure out what I'm missing.

I've gone through and used `beam.RegisterFunction()` for all of my functions that `emit` and also used `beam.RegisterType()` for the top-level struct I'm passing around.

Any ideas how this error connects to the code I've written / how I can debug?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ParDo did not have a ParDoPayload
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.RegisterNodeFunction.apply(RegisterNodeFunction.java:327)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.RegisterNodeFunction.apply(RegisterNodeFunction.java:97)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.apply(CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.java:207)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.apply(CreateRegisterFnOperationFunction.java:74)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:346)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:305)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowRunnerHarness.start(DataflowRunnerHarness.java:195)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowRunnerHarness.main(DataflowRunnerHarness.java:123)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8.
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidUtf8(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.Utf8$DecodeUtil.handleTwoBytes(Utf8.java:1909)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.Utf8$DecodeUtil.access$700(Utf8.java:1883)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnsafeProcessor.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:1411)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.Utf8.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:340)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readStringRequireUtf8(CodedInputStream.java:804)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec.<init>(RunnerApi.java:55936)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec.<init>(RunnerApi.java:55897)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec$1.parsePartialFrom(RunnerApi.java:56565)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$FunctionSpec$1.parsePartialFrom(RunnerApi.java:56559)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:883)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$ParDoPayload.<init>(RunnerApi.java:10363)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$ParDoPayload.<init>(RunnerApi.java:10320)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$ParDoPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(RunnerApi.java:12633)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$ParDoPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(RunnerApi.java:12627)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:100)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:125)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p21p0.com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
    at org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$ParDoPayload.parseFrom(RunnerApi.java:11130)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.RegisterNodeFunction.apply(RegisterNodeFunction.java:325)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: While having no idea about protobuf, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139449) seems to be related. If you `string`s contain non-AASCII characters, you might need to use bytes instead of strings

Comment: Notice the original exception is `InvalidProtocolBufferException`. I believe this is caused by using a worker harness that isn't compatible with Dataflow. Dataflow unfortunately doesn't officially support Go yet. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016340/apache-beam-go-sdk-with-dataflow.